# How to refactor commonalities among InputActionMaps in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, architecture, refactoring, code-duplication

Suppose I have 2 (or more) types of objects that the user can control:

```
public class Runner : MonoBehaviour
{
    //...
    public void Run() { //... }
}
```

and

```
public class Jumper : Runner
{
    //...
    public void Jump() { //... }
}
```

Furthermore, we have the following InputActionMaps in our InputActionAsset:

[runner action map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVreL.png)

[jumper action map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj95k.png)

My current solution defines the control-to-action mappings using separate "Controls" classes.

Controls.cs:

```
public abstract class Controls<T>
{
    protected T controlled;

    public Controls(InputActionMap actionMap, T controlled)
    {
        SetupInputCallbacks(actionMap);
        this.controlled = controlled;
    }

    protected abstract void SetupInputCallbacks(InputActionMap actionMap);
 }
```

RunnerControls.cs

```
public class RunnerControls : Controls<Runner>
{
    public RunnerControls(InputActionMap actionMap, Runner controlled)
        : base(actionMap, controlled) { }

    protected override void SetupInputCallbacks(InputActionMap actionMap)
    {
        InputAction runAction = actionMap.FindAction("Run");
        runAction.perform += controlled.Run();
    }
}
```

Jumper.cs

```
public class JumperControls : Controls<Jumper>
{
    public JumperControls(InputActionMap actionMap, Runner controlled)
        : base(actionMap, controlled) { }

    protected override void SetupInputCallbacks(InputActionMap actionMap)
    {
        InputAction runAction = actionMap.FindAction("Run");
        runAction.perform += controlled.Run();

        InputAction jumpAction = actionMap.FindAction("Jump");
        jumpAction.perform += controlled.Jump();
    }
}
```

The code for the "run action" is duplicated, and although this may seem minor here, my actual code does this to a much greater extent. I tried something like `public class JumperControls : RunnerControls`, but then the `controlled.Jump()` would fail since the `T` in the `Controls` class evaluates to `Runner`. If anyone can help me come up with a solution to this that'd be a huge help, even if that means changing the architecture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `Runner` and `Jumper` separate interfaces with their respective `Run` and `Jump` methods. The actual monobehaviours will be implementing the interfaces and having their own `Run` and `Jump` logic. So in the `Controls<T>` you can check whether the `T` implements the respective interface:

```
public class Controls<T>
{
    protected T controlled;

    public Controls(InputActionMap actionMap, T controlled)
    {
        SetupInputCallbacks(actionMap);
        this.controlled = controlled;
    }

    protected virtual void SetupInputCallbacks(InputActionMap actionMap)
    {
        if (T is Runner) ....
        if (T is Jumper) ....
    }
 }
```

Comment: This was actually quite helpful. Thank you!